# In the 1924 version of The Thief of Bagdad, no character is named, right?

Tags: the-thief-of-bagdad

Are any characters in the 1924 version of *The Thief of Bagdad* named?

I'm finding contradicting information on this. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_of_Bagdad_(1924_film)) gives names to characters, but [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheThiefOfBagdad1924) doesn't and a quick skim of the first few minutes seems to show that there are no names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are any characters in the 1924 version of The Thief of Bagdad named?

Yes.

The film is a [silent movie with a musical soundtrack](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015400/technical?ref_=ttloc_sa_5), occasionally writing appears and infrequently people are specifically named. Example: "[**Harun al-Rashid**](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=43m45s)" (the [fifth Abbasid Caliph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbasid_Caliphate#Abbasid_Golden_Age_(775%E2%80%93861))), "[**Cham Shang**](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=49m20s)" ([prince of the Mongrels](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Cham_Shang)), "[**Ahmed**, prince of the isles](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=51m14s)" (the thief of Bagdad, posing as a prince), "[this **Ahmed** who calls himself a prince, hunt him down](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=1h9m31s)", "[the learned doctor, **Zakariya of Kufa**](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=7431)" or "[Great **Khan**](https://youtu.be/fQ8KCfCu23I?t=2h21m46s)" (another reference to Cham Shang).

Wikipedia mentions a few characters but IMDb reveals the [full cast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015400/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm), their names, and the production crew, where it was filmed and technical details, even a [photo gallery](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015400/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_mi_sm). The listing of the cast is complete but the naming of each character is lacking. Also see [Heritage Auctions list of 112 movie posters](https://movieposters.ha.com/c/search-results.zx?N=54%20790%20231&Nty=1&Ntt=The%20Thief%20of%20Bagdad&Ntk=SI_Titles&searchView=list&ic4=ListView-071515).

Comment: You say that "IMDb reveals the full cast", which is all well and good. But unless I'm missing something it *doesn't* seem to list any names for the characters either in that cast list. The rest of the answer still makes sense (especially the specific reference to the title cards), but the last paraghraph about IMDb seems rather unrelated to the question.

Comment: Malandy's second paragraph says that Wikipedia and TV Tropes were consulted, and that contradictions and a quick skim of the first few minutes of the film have led to the question. --- I used a single sentence to explain that one needs to review more than the first few minutes and another sentence to offer IMDb as a source of additional information on the cast and other aspects of the film, it is a definitive source.